# Creating and extending objects in javascript overwrites base object's variables

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a basic wrapper for Object.create to be used for our application. Basically the process is to use `Object.create` on a parent object, then `.extend({})` to add new functionality to it. If we need to call a method on the parent class, we just use `ParentClass.myFunc.apply(this, arguments);` in the method override. The issue I'm having is when I intialize an object and call the `init` function of the parent object, it overrides the parent' object's properties. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here's the main Object.create wrapper:

```
/**
 * Simple wrapper for Object.create and Object.extend
 * functionality.
 */
var My_Object = {
    /**
     * Simple extend function for inheritance
     * @param props An object of functions to place in the new object.
     * @returns {My_Object}
     */
    extend: function(props) {
        for(var prop in props)
            this[prop] = props[prop];

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Basic function that checks if a function is native or user-created
     * @author Yong (http://stackoverflow.com/users/962254/yong)
     *
     * @param f The function to test if it is native
     * @returns {boolean}
     *
     * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598945/detect-if-function-is-native-to-browser
     */
    isFuncNative: function(f) {
        return !!f && (typeof f).toLowerCase() == 'function'
            && (f === Function.prototype
            || /^\s*function\s*(\b[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*\b)*\s*\((|([a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)(\s*,[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)*)\)\s*{\s*\[native code\]\s*}\s*$/i.test(String(f)));
    },


    /**
     * Simple polyfill wrapper for native Object.create. Using a polyfill
     * instead of native incase for some reason consumer would have overwritten
     * it with unexpected usage.
     */
    create: function(obj) {
        // If the browser supports Object.create and hasn't been overwritten,
        // use the native version instead of the polyfill
        if(My_Object.isFuncNative(Object.create)) {
            // If extend hasn't been defined, add it
            if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('extend'))
                obj.extend = My_Object.extend;

            return Object.create(obj);
        }


        // Create empty function for polyfill
        function F(){}
        F.prototype = o;

        // If extend hasn't been defined, add it
        if(!F.prototype.extend)
            F.prototype.extend = My_Object.extend;

        return new F()
    }
};
```

Then I define a base object:

```
var SomeParentObject = {
    options: {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    },

    init: function(options) {
        this.options = $.extend(this.options, options || {});

        return this;
    }
};
```

And some children object:

```
var ChildObject1 = My_Object.create(SomeParentObject).extend({
    init: function() {
        SomeParentObject.init.call(this, {b: 'c'});        

        return this;
    }
}).init();

var ChildObject2 = My_Object.create(SomeParentObject).extend({}).init();
```

Now the desired result is that `SomeParentObject`'s options should never be modified. I can't figure out what exactly is the cause of it, but I'm sure it's something stupid I'm doing. If you do some basic `console.log`s, you can see that when `ChildObject2` has some options to override, it overrides it for `SomeParentObject`, and therefore for all children.

```
console.log('<<SomeParentObject.a, SomeParentObject.b>>');
console.log(SomeParentObject.options.a + ', ' + SomeParentObject.options.b);

console.log('<<ChildObject1.a, ChildeObject1.b>>');
console.log(ChildObject1.options.a + ', ' + ChildObject1.options.b);

console.log('<<ChildObject2.a, ChildeObject2.b>>');
console.log(ChildObject2.options.a + ', ' + ChildObject2.options.b);
```

Which outputs:

```
<<SomeParentObject.a, SomeParentObject.b>>
a, c
<<ChildObject1.a, ChildeObject1.b>>
a, c
<<ChildObject2.a, ChildeObject2.b>>
a, c
```

What should be outputted is this:

```
<<SomeParentObject.a, SomeParentObject.b>>
a, b
<<ChildObject1.a, ChildeObject1.b>>
a, c
<<ChildObject2.a, ChildeObject2.b>>
a, b
```

Comment: Please show an alternative output, which you would consider being correct.

Comment: Right, thank you for reminding me

Comment: When I do not use a deep copy in jQuerys "extend" method, like so: this.options = jQuery.extend(false,this.options, options || {}), and then use native Object.create(SomeParentObject); then call init: ChildObject1.init.call(ChildObject1,{b: 'c'}); --> the integrity of the data is intact. returns: Object { a="a", b="c"} Object { a="a", b="b"} ==> so, I think perhaps the issue manifests itself in your custom extend methods.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that you needed to use false. That worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the way prototyping works in JavaScript in order to achieve a simple way of inheritance and OOP, I'd suggest taking a look at this:  https://github.com/haroldiedema/joii

It basically allows you to do the following (and more):

```
// First (bottom level)
var Person = new Class(function() {
    this.name = "Unknown Person";
});

// Employee, extend on Person & apply the Role property.
var Employee = new Class({ extends: Person }, function() {
    this.name = 'Unknown Employee';
    this.role = 'Employee';

    this.getValue = function() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
});

// 3rd level, extend on Employee. Modify existing properties.
var Manager = new Class({ extends: Employee }, function() {

    // Overwrite the value of 'role'.
    this.role = this.role + ': Manager';

    // Class constructor to apply the given 'name' value.
    this.__construct = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Parent inheritance & override
    this.getValue = function() {
        return this.parent.getValue().toUpperCase();
    }
});

// And to use the final result:
var myManager = new Manager("John Smith");
console.log( myManager.name ); // John Smith
console.log( myManager.role ); // Manager

console.log( myManager.getValue() ); // HELLO WORLD
```