# How to detect if object is one of built in JavaScript objects or not

Tags: javascript

I need a way to detect if prototype is built in JavaScript object (default prototype) as Object, Array, Date, Function etc.. Or is it custom user defined object.

Consider following code

```
const a = { a: 1 };
const b = Object.create(a);

const aProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(a); // Default prototype
const bProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(b); // User defined prototype

// One way to detect it would be 
aProto === Object.prototype; // [true] we know it's default object
bProto === Object.prototype; // [false]
```

Above check would require to test for Array.prototype, Function.prototype, Date.prototype, etc...

Is there smarter way to achieve this?

**Added**

Context of what I'm trying to achieve. I want to modify object properties then I want to go over his prototype chain and do the same for objects on his prototype up until I reach the built in object that I want to skip without modifying.

In example from above I would modify all properties of object b then I would go to his prototype which is object a and modify all of his properties. Then I would go to prototype of a which is now built in object. I would like to detect that a have built in object as prototype and skip modifications.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/detect-native-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if function is native to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598945/detect-if-function-is-native-to-browser)

Comment: @gurvinder372 is `[native function]` being returned part of a spec?  I only ask because I wonder if there is a more apt reason to need to detect if something is native or not.  If there is, maybe there is a less brittle approach (I mean, if that way is even brittle).

Comment: @zero298 Not sure, I can't find the same in the spec itself.

Comment: I need to detect if object prototype is one of built in objects prototypes. I don't need to test if function is native or not so I'm not able to use solutions from above. [built in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).