# Is the global JavaScript object in the browser fully mutable?

Tags: javascript, browser

Let's say I want to call `fetch` but I want to be sure it's the native one provided by the browser. Is it possible to determine that somehow? If it's been replaced for example:

```
window.fetch = function() { alert('not real'); }
```

Can I access the "real" one via the `Window` prototype? If so, is the prototype mutable?

Comment: Some properties are immutable, some (like `fetch`) are not. If you want to make sure that nothing has replaced the value, don't run scripts in your page that you don't control.

Comment: Note that there are always ways to find the original methods (e.g through an iframe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599105/14596856